# How to set default option on configurable product dropdown attribute?

Tags: attributes, configurable-product, magento-1, product-attribute, phtml

How to set first value attribute as selected for a configurable product?

Front-end:

> Size:
>
> - **Choose an Option...** (selected)
> - Small
> - Medium

I would like to change it to...

> Size:
>
> - **Small** (selected)
> - Medium

configurable.phtml

```
<?php
$_product    = $this->getProduct();
$_attributes = Mage::helper('core')->decorateArray($this->getAllowAttributes());
$_jsonConfig = $this->getJsonConfig();
$_renderers = $this->getChild('attr_renderers')->getSortedChildren();
?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && count($_attributes)):?>
    <dl>
    <?php foreach($_attributes as $_attribute): ?>
        <?php
        $_rendered = false;
        foreach ($_renderers as $_rendererName):
            $_renderer = $this->getChild('attr_renderers')->getChild($_rendererName);
            if (method_exists($_renderer, 'shouldRender') && $_renderer->shouldRender($_product, $_attribute, $_jsonConfig)):
                $_renderer->setProduct($_product);
                $_renderer->setAttributeObj($_attribute);
                echo $_renderer->toHtml();
                $_rendered = true;
                break;
            endif;
        endforeach;

        if (!$_rendered):
        ?>
        <dt><label class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $_attribute->getLabel() ?></label></dt>
        <dd<?php if ($_attribute->decoratedIsLast){?> class="last"<?php }?>>
            <div class="input-box">
                <select name="super_attribute[<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]" id="attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>" class="required-entry super-attribute-select">
                    <option><?php echo $this->__('Choose an Option...') ?></option>
                  </select>
              </div>
        </dd>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </dl>
<?php
$jsonConfig = json_decode($this->getJsonConfig());
$jsonConfig->chooseText = $_attribute->getLabel();
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var spConfig = new Product.Config(<?php echo json_encode($jsonConfig); ?>);
</script>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after') ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 1):

goto   `/app/design/frontend/your_package/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/options` and open`configurable.phtml`

find for this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var spConfig = new Product.Config(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
</script>
```

and replace with

```
<?php
$jsonConfig = json_decode($this->getJsonConfig());
$jsonConfig->chooseText = $_attribute->getLabel();
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var spConfig = new Product.Config(<?php echo json_encode($jsonConfig); ?>);
</script>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after') ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Yes it won't give first attribute value but attribute label you should fetch attributes values and then display them before posting this answer i tried for that but I failed so atleast I thought of posting this so that you can have some idea and can try.

Comment: `eav_attribute_option_value` this is the table which store attribute set values so please try fetching values from this table.